# How to flat multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with MultiIndex and `level=[0,1]` does not seem to work.

```
MultiIndex([('Datetime',    ''),
            (   'Value', 'A'),
            (   'Value', 'B')],
           names=[None, 'Col1'])



        Datetime               Value
Col1                           A          B
0       2017-10-14 00:00:00   -0.540774   0.870280
1       2017-10-14 01:00:00   -0.426617   0.720261
2       2017-10-14 02:00:00   -0.053588   0.746738
3       2017-10-14 03:00:00   0.318062    0.871044
4       2017-10-14 04:00:00   0.478168    1.060897
```

I tried to use `.reset_index(level = [0,1])` as suggested in many similar questions, but it does not work.

Comment: How do you want to flatten the multi index? *What does the new index look like?

Comment: @HenryEcker I want to get `Col1, Datetime, A, B`: all at the same level.

Comment: So remove `Value` completely?

Comment: @HenryEcker: Yes.

Comment: Please show the command used to set the multiindex. Also show how the result of `.reset_index(level = [0,1])` is wrong, don't just say *"but it does not work"*. Otherwise this isn't reproducible ([mcve]) and not very reusable for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df.columns = [col[1] if col[0] == '' else col[0] for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: You can also do `df.columns = [col[1] or col[0] for col in df.columns]`